# HackerRank Weather Observation Station 11

Tags: mysql, sql

*Query the list of CITY names from STATION that either does not start with vowels or do not end with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.*

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY NOT IN ('%a','%e','%i','%o','%u') OR CITY NOT IN ('a%','e%','i%','o%','u%');
```

This is giving me the names of all the cities.

Comment: Hi @Ismriti Gupta, The point of solving `hackerrank` assignments is for you to research and learn as much as you can. Try researching how `IN` operator works in SQL and whether it will filter with `WILDCARD` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard characters can't use with in. You should use like operator for use wildcard characters.

Solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION
WHERE (NOT(CITY LIKE 'A%' OR CITY LIKE 'E%' OR CITY LIKE 'O%' OR CITY LIKE 'I%' OR CITY LIKE 'U%')) OR 
(NOT (CITY LIKE '%a' OR CITY LIKE '%e' OR CITY LIKE '%i' OR CITY LIKE '%o' OR CITY LIKE '%u'))
ORDER BY CITY;
```